# Andengine fade in/out and alpha modifiers not working

Tags: android, andengine, fade, alpha, andengine-gles-2

I have a problem with AndEngine GLES2.

I have this code:

```
Sprite black = new Sprite(0,0, blackRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
black.setSize(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

black.registerEntityModifier(new AlphaModifier(2, 0, 255));

mScene.attachChild(black);
```

So it's not working. Nothing does...

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you set the blend function properly? Example:

```
sprite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above but it's not working for me as it should. The modifier works but instead of a steady fade out the image fades out a number of times for the mentioned duration. Any ideas?

Well ultimately i figured out what i was doing wrong. Here's it...

```
        anySprite.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    IEntityModifier iem = new AlphaModifier(seconds, 0, 255); //for some unknown reason i was passing invalid values and hence it didn't work then :)
    iem.setRemoveWhenFinished(true);
    anySprite.registerEntityModifier(iem);
```

Comment: Yeah me too... What do we need to do?

Comment: The reason you are fading out multiple times is because the AlphaModifier goes from a scale of 0.0f to 1.0f instead of 0 to 255. where 1.0f is 255 on a regular color wheel.